# HTTPS for GoDaddy - AWS S3 static website

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, https, cname

I want to host a HTTPS-only static website using Amazon S3 and GoDaddy. Here's what I've done so far:

```
 a) Created S3 static website at Amazon 
 b) Added S3 static URL at GoDaddy's CNAME records
     CNAME **NAME**: *WWW* and **HOST** : *mywebsite.com.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com*  
 c) Then in forwading **Domain** section added http://mywebsite.com
```

Now, I can access my website using http://mywebsite.com address. However, I want the site to be available via HTTPS only, for which I bought an SSL certificate from GoDaddy. And did setup on GoDaddy.

Now, the question is:
Is there a way to have an automatic http to https redirect with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for an Amazon S3 Bucket. Amazon published [Key Differences Between the Amazon Website and the REST API Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff) to highlight website hosting on s3 does not support SSL connections.

However, this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/) by Amazon will walk you through creating a CloudFront distribution to serve s3 content using HTTPS.